# Cypress assertion getting iframe

Tags: iframe, css-selectors, cypress, timeout

```
import 'cypress-iframe'
cy.iframe('[id="Your project: \'Test Project\'"]').within(() => {my code abc})
```

```
Timed out retrying after 10000ms: Expected to find element: [id="Your project: 'Test Project'"], but never found it.`
```

where as 'id' can be found in inspect elements of chrome, so what's the issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfhBV.png)

**image clearly shows id is present but never hit???**
issue generates only in inner iframe, outer iframes works well

```
cy.get('.col.right').within(() => {
      cy.iframe('iframe[name="mail"]').within(() => {
        cy.get('div#container').within(() => {
          cy.iframe('iframe[seamless]').within(() => {
            cy.get('[data-cy="reset-password-btn"]')
            .should('exist')
            .should('be.visible')          
            .should('not.have.attr', 'disabled')
            cy.get('[data-cy="reset-password-btn"]').then(($el) => {
              const href = $el.attr('href');
              if (href) {
                cy.log('Reset Password Link:', href);
                cy.visit(href);
                cy.wait(1000)
                cy.url()
                .wait(1000)
                .should('include', '/users/password/edit?reset_password_token')
                cy.pause()
                //form action="/users/password"
                //iframe[id="Your project: 'Test Project'"]
                cy.iframe('[id="Your project: \'Test Project\'"]').within(() => {
                  cy.log('inside iframe change password')
                  cy.wait(3000)
                  cy.get('[data-cy="change-password-title"]')
                  cy.get('[data-cy="enter-new-password"]')
                  .should('be.visible')
                  .should('exist')
                  .should('not.have.attr', 'disabled')
                  //////
                  cy.pause()
                  cy.get('[data-cy="enter-new-password"]')
                  .type("T%789ghjk")
                  cy.get('[data-cy="confirm-new-password"]')
                  .type("T%789ghjk")
                  cy.get('[data-cy="submit"]')
    
                  cy.get('.toast-message')
                  .contains("Your password has been changed successfully. You are now signed in.");
                })
               
              }else {
                
                cy.log('Reset Password Link does not have href attribute');
                
              }
             
            });
            

          });
        });
      });
    });
```

This is complete code where issue generate in inner iframe, where id string have space in between,other iframe handle well